# Can we use Express JS in AWS Amplify?

Tags: express, aws-amplify

I have an app which build by aws-amplify, but now I want to add expressjs as server to add some server side logic. Is it possible to do it? I cannot find any suggestion or description for this from aws amplify document.

Can someone help me? Many thanks

Comment: You can visit AMPLIFY's Docs to learn more about it. Just visit this link: https://docs.amplify.aws/guides/api-rest/express-server/q/platform/js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add server side logic using an API either using REST or GraphQL. In order to do this you can use `amplify add api` together with `anplify push`.

If you want to use ExpressJS you can also do it within a function.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")
  next()
});
// below the last app.use() method, add the following code 
const axios = require('axios')

app.get('/coins', function(req, res) {
  let apiUrl = `https://api.coinlore.com/api/tickers?start=0&limit=10`

  console.log(req.query);
  if (req && req.query) {
    const { start = 0, limit = 10 } = req.query
    apiUrl = `https://api.coinlore.com/api/tickers/?start=${start}&limit=${limit}`
  }
  axios.get(apiUrl)
    .then(response => {
      res.json({
        coins: response.data.data
      })
    })
    .catch(err => res.json({ error: err }))
})
```

[Workshop](https://github.com/dabit3/aws-amplify-workshop-react#adding-a-function-running-an-express-server)